# AngularJS: Creating drop-down list without scope variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

Just wondering if theres a way of creating a drop down list without using scope. For example:

Currently in my javascript file i declare $scope.readWrite = ['R','W'] and then use the following to create a drop down list with it.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Read/Write:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select class="form-control"
            ng-options="item for item in readWrite"
            ng-model="singleRegister.RW"
            ng-change="modbusChange(modbusDetailsEdit)">
        </select>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way of manipulating ng-options so that I can add the items in the list there, for example (know this isnt correct but gets my point across) : ... ng-options=["R","W"] ...

Im having problems with the scope variable in my existing code so was wanting to try something like this as a quick fix.

Comment: Where are you going to get `ng-model` without scope?

Comment: Hopefully it would not be required as I would like to replace that entire line of code with something that works very simply to get the output i require (if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    <select class="form-control"
        ng-options="item for item in ['R','W']"
        ng-model="singleRegister.RW"
        ng-change="modbusChange(modbusDetailsEdit)">
    </select>
```